# How to disable collapse event of a Section in Orbeon Forms?

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I want to disable collapse event of a section, when clicking on it, in Orbeon Forms, but **NOT** through properties but in runtime.

Disable collapse through *properties-form-runner.xml*(this works!):

```
<property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.detail.noscript.section.collapse.*.*" value="false"/>
```

Isn't there a way to disable *"fr-collapse" event* when clicking a Section in runtime?

Something like : 
`<fr:section id="table-grid" bind="table-bind" collapse="false">`?

*Using Orbeon Forms 4.5*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You couldn't override the values of properties with attributes on `fr:section`, but this would make sense, so I did [this change](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2292) per your suggestion, and it will be possible in the upcoming Orbeon Forms 4.10.